# delete query to send a mail depending on field value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a delete query below from a php page where the user types in an extension number and the entry is deleted from the database.

Name,Email,Extension,Phone,Department the whole line is deleted by entering the extension number of the database member.

Now I have phpmailer installed and working for this, it is sending a mail to IT@sadsa.com but I am trying to make it also send the mail to another address before the member is deleted from the database depending on the department they are in.

Eg. if they are in Sales department then the email must be sent to `sales@sadsa.com` and `IT@sada.com`, if they are in the Admin Department then the mail must be sent to `Admin@sadsa.com` and `IT@asdas.com.`

My current code below :

delete.php  (the php page where the user enters the extension number to delete)

```
<?php

    require ("database.php");  
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['CheckLogin'])) { header("Location: login.php"); }

    $this_user_ext =$_REQUEST['extension'];

        // sending query
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext'")
        or die(mysql_error());          

        if($_POST['action']) {

            include('maildelete.php');
            $extension=$_POST['extension'];
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
?>
<center><form action="" method="post">
Enter 4 Digit Extension Number :<br><input type="text" name="extension"><br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete!">
<br> <br>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a> 

</h3>
</form>
</center>
```

maildelete.php (this is the script that sends the mail to IT@sad.com)

```
<?php

    $extension = $_POST['extension'];
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.titan-networks.co.za"; // SMTP server                     // enables SMTP debug information 
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "mail.titan-networks.co.za"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "jurgen@titan-networks.co.za"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "****";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->From = "no-reply@alpinemotors.co.za";
    $mail->FromName = "Extension List";
    $mail->AddAddress('jurgen@titan-networks.co.za', "");
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject  = 'Extension Deleted';
    $mail->Body     = "Extension Number " . $extension . " was removed from the Extension List";

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
    echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
?>
```

Comment: If someone uses this as the GET query, it will delete the entire table's contents: `?extension=' OR 'A' = 'A`

Comment: what would I do with that code sir?

Comment: Your code is at risk for SQL injection. The above is a demonstration of said injection.

Comment: I understand sir. I'll fix that. This is just the last part of this website I need to do.